# Parameters for activation page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am just completely stumped at this and so is my buddy who created this template system.

I have a registration page that sends the user an email with a link to the account activation page in which they must fill out there password to confirm. Inside the link is their user_id and a random string for a registration key.

Here's what I normal url would look like :

kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/activate/10000/da54d6fad5fa5fadf

What I want to do is if either of these statements are true then it shows my 404 error page:

1. Doesn't have the user_id in the url
2. Doesn't have the registration key in the url
3. Doesn't have either the two parameters in the url

Activate Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Activate extends CI_Controller 
{ 

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('kow_auth');            
}   

public function index($param1 = NULL, $param2 = NULL)
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons = '<script src="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/assets/js/activatevalidate.js"></script>';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    $x = 0;
    if(($param1 !== NULL)&&($param2 !== NULL))
    {
        //params not null yay..
        if((isset($param1))&&((trim($param1) !== '')||(!empty($param1))))
        {
            if(!is_numeric($param1))
            {
              $x++;
            } 
        }
        if((isset($param2))&&((trim($param2) !== '')||(!empty($param2))))
        {
            if(!is_string($param2))
            {
              $x++;
            } 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $x++;
    }


    if($x !== 0)
    {
       $bodyContent = "error_page";
    }
    else
    {
       $bodyContent = "activate_form";
    }



    $bodyType = "full";//type of template

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.      
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads 
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['metaAddons'] = $metaAddons;//if there is any addictional meta data to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['pageMetaTags'] = $this->metatags->MetaTags();//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->load->view('usermanagement/index', $this->data);
}

function activate_submit()
{        
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|alpha_numeric');

    $user_id            = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $registration_key   = $this->uri->segment(4);

    if (($registration_key == '') OR ($user_id == ''))
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'URL was not complete!')); 
    }
    else
    {
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) 
        {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'There was a problem submitting the form! Please refresh the window and try again!'));    
        }
        else
        {                           
            if ($this->kow_auth->activate_user($user_id, $registration_key, $this->input->post('password'))) 
            {
                echo json_encode(array('sucess' => 'yes', 'message' => 'Your account has been successfully activated!'));
            } 
            else 
            {                                                           
                echo json_encode(array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'The activation code you entered is incorrect or expired!'));
            }
        }
    }


}

}

/* End of file activate.php */ 
/* Location: ./application/controllers/activate.php */
```

Routes:

```
$route['activate/:num/:any'] = 'activate/index/$1/$2';
$route['404_override'] = 'error';
```

Here's what I'm getting for each of those instances:

kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/activate    - correct

kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/activate/10000/  - correct

kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/activate/10000/271cce33ab11ced5fd10aeca41323a3c   -  incorrect should be showing the activate form

**EDIT :**  Anybody have any ideas because it just seems like nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by simplifying a bit the params checking:

```
$this->error = FALSE;

if(NULL != $param1 AND NULL != $param2)
{
   if(!is_numeric($param1) OR (string)trim($param2)!= '')
   {
     $this->error = TRUE;
   }
}
else
{
  $this->error = TRUE;
}

$this->data['bodyContent'] = $this->error? 'error_page' : 'activate_form';
```

It's late here so I might messed up something, but basically:

1. if both params are null, set $error to TRUE (they don't have to be null);
2. if at least one isn't null:
       - if param1 isn't numeric (userid) or 
       - if param2 isn't a string (nor even an empty one), $error is again TRUE.

In the end, if error is FALSE (as initialized), we pass the "activate_form" value to the view, else (i.e. if any of the above condition caused the error to be set to TRUE), we pass the "error_page" value.

Also, as per documentation, custom routes should go *after* fixed ones:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'error';
$route['activate/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'activate/index/$1/$2';
```

Comment: Exactly the same situation? works for the first two but not the last route?

Comment: No it works when there are NO parameters HOWEVER if there's only the user_id then it gives an odd error message AND if there are both parameters it goes to the 404 page which it shouldn't because it should be showing the activation view

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[Tank Auth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/)**

It is a CI library that already does this, but with a key difference, you don't want to pass more than you have to.  So just generate a HASH (encrypted for instance), that lets you find the userid & activate at the same time.

It is less checking and less issues with copy & pasting URL.  Also eliminates having to do all this **extra checking** of ID validity + hash validity.

But as I said, look at the tank auth code, and pull out what you need for the activation part, it's fairly straight forward, and already for CI.

Comment: This would hold some merit if the question was revolving around some need for an over weight concept as Tank Auth. but the question seems to be asking something a routing issue more than something to do with that actual verification handling.

Comment: @chris, I agree, I was attempting to provide an alternative, simplified approach where Jeff doesn't need to validate 2 things, and have multiple conditions (bad user, bad hash, valid user, bad hash, etc;)

Comment: Tank you Jakub but this is the route is like to go with my script however I still can't figure out why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity...what happens if you remove the following line?

```
if(!is_string($param2))
```

And you just have:

```
if((isset($param2))&&((trim($param2) !== '')||(!empty($param2))))
{
$x++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to create a new controlller/module for account activation, simply add a new method inside your existing auth controller/module.

IF you setup a route with conditions and they fail, your shown an error or 404.

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct(){parent::__construct();}
    /**
     * Activate user account
     * $route['activate/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'auth/activate/$1/$2';
     */
    public function activate($uid, $code)
    {

        //if need be, double check
        if(!$uid OR !$code){show_404();} //BOTH need to exists

        //if $route['activate/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'auth/activate/$1/$2'; FAILS CI will show error or 404

        //grab $code and $uid and seek a match from DB, if failure do your own errors.
    }
}
```

I would suggest removing the user id from the uri segment and make the activation code a UNIQUE db constraint so you only have to query for that.

Comment: I don't have an auth controller. I have a login/logout/activate/register controllers. I dd this to make it easier with my template System I have

Comment: perhaps you didn't understand what I said before I don't want an auth controller.

Comment: I understood your question, I only got round to reading your reply.  Like I have said CI will look after any URI segment failure for you provided you set conditions in the route.  rename class Auth to Activate and re-route to there.  Just tell the route you expect an int or string(CI will also look for allowed_uri_chars) so really all you need to do is query the DB to make sure the key is correct.